# Is there a way I can make a HTML5 video display a div at a specific point in the video?

Tags: javascript, html, video, popup, html5-video

I want to get a popup to appear when a HTML5 video gets to a certain point, for example; 34 seconds into the video...

I have the popup in a div and I just need to find a way to make it only appear once the video has hit a specific time mark.  I can't have it just time how long the user is on the page though... (which makes it a bit harder....!) it has to be from the video is played.

Is this somehow possible?

```
  <video class="fs-video" preload="auto" >
    <source  class="fs-video"  src="videos/scene1_option1a.mp4"  type="video/mp4" > 
    </video>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [timeupdate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) which runs when video progress. But it triggers at each update so to solve that maintain a flag and check if popup is already shown

Here's a demo for 6 seconds

```js
var popupShown = false

var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
  if ((e.target.currentTime > 6) && !popupShown) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    popupShown = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <video class="fs-video" preload="auto" id="myVideo" controls>
  <source  class="fs-video"  src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4"   type="video/mp4" >
</video>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Video is at 6 seconds.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The video tag as a property called "currentTime" which returns (or sets) the playback position in seconds. So I think the best course of action would be a javascript setInterval function that continuously checks that property, and fires when the time is 34:

```js
setInterval (function(){
 var curTime = document.getElementById("vidId").currentTime;

 if (curTime == 34) {
  document.getElementById("divId").style.visibility = "visible"
 }
},500);
```

```html
<video id="vidId"></video>
<div id="divId" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
```